# Stop blindly closing questions please!

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, reviews

I am really enjoying that there are so many users already with the [close-vote casting privilege](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) and actively using the [review queue tools](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/review) to help maintaining this site.

However, while going through [flags](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) I often notice, some questions are closed with the following reason:

> This question **does not appear to be about Ethereum, the decentralized application platform and smart contract enabled blockchain**, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help).

This is not certainly true for some questions like [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15724/how-many-shares-i-got-submitted-or-checked-by-this-claymore-display?noredirect=1) and I notice this happens quite often in relation with [mining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining). In my eyes mining is an essential part of Ethereum and clearly on-topic.

If the question is of low quality, vote down and add a comment to help new users on-boarding by explaining how the question could be improved. If the question is hardly salvageable, use the *unclear what you are asking* reason. (And so on.)

But please don't close questions as *off-topic* which clearly relate to Ethereum. Discuss below if you disagree. Thanks :)

Edit: [Another one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/16576/87).

Comment: Thank you for this note, me and some firends are "suffering" some times from  incomprehensible closure of our questions.

Comment: Feel free to always raise issues on meta.

Comment: While I agree that your first example question is clearly on-topic, I'm not so sure about the second. While it is generally related to mining, it's not specific to Ethereum in any way, and is specifically a question solely about GPU hardware. Is there some rule of thumb we can use for deciding these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Mining questions are important. In my opinion we need some of the expertise and experts from r/EtherMining/. Maybe an invitation from a mod or redditor with high reputation to EtherMining redditors could help.

Answer (score 0):

I actually seem to disagree with a lot of the replies here. Questions like [your first example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15724/how-many-shares-i-got-submitted-or-checked-by-this-claymore-display?noredirect=1) are way too broad. While it's on-topic, it asks several different questions at once -- too many to be adequately answered in one answer. I think that example should definitely be closed as too broad or edited to be more clear.